# An injective continuous map between two compact Hausdorff spaces.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, banach-algebras

As I was reading Gelfand theory, I got stuck at a proposition where I am supposed to show that A continuous function between two compact Hausdorff spaces is a Homoeomorphism if some conditions are satisfied.

But in the proof, they have written that it is sufficient to prove that the map is injective.
I didn't get this point, is there any result which I don't know or am I missing something.

kindly help Thanks and regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The map is closed: For closed subset $F$ in the domain which is compact Hausdorff, then $F$ is compact, so $A(F)$ is compact in the range which is compact Hausdorff as well, so $A(F)$ is closed.

Injective closed continuous map is a homeomorphism (onto its range).

Comment: I don't understand? So you are given that the map is onto? Then it is good.

Comment: Actually my answer says that, the map is injective, closed, and continuous. This is very closed to homeomorphism, that some books define homeomorphism for injective, open, and continuous.

Comment: Like this: $f:X\rightarrow Y$, $f$ is injective, closed, continuous, then $f:X\rightarrow f(X)$ is a homeomorphism in the classical sense, where $f(X)$ equips the subspace topology.

Comment: You can switch to open. It depends on the books whether bijective is needed. As I said, some books define homeomorphisms for injective open continuous maps, but this is no that far away from "bijective", just to restrict the codomain to be its range $f(X)$ equipped with the subspace topology.

Comment: yes I got your point. thanks

Comment: To generalize this result slightly; we don’t need the domain to be Hausdorff or the codomain to be compact for this argument to work. It is sufficient that the domain is compact and that the codomain is Hausdorff.