# Isn't a continuous and injective application $f:S^1\to \mathbf{R}^3$ sufficient to define a knot?

Tags: general-topology, knot-theory

**Definition:**
A knot can be defined as an embedding $f:S^1 \to \mathbf{R}^3$, *i.e.* as a continuous, injective map from $S^1$ to $\mathbf{R^3}$ which realizes a homeomorphism on its image (*Porter - Knots and Surfaces (1994), p46. for embedding, p52. for knot*).

I fully understand the following points:

- Requiring the continuity of $f$ is natural, otherwise the image of $S^1$ could be in several pieces.
- Requiring the injectivity of $f$ is also very understandable, otherwise double points would appear.

**Question:**
Is the continuity of the function $f^{-1}: f\left(S^1\right) \to S^1$ really necessary when defining a knot?

I tried to find examples of continuous and injective maps $f:S^1\to\mathbf{R}^3$ strange enough for a problem to arise, without success.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Any continuous, injective map from a compact space into a Hausdorff space is a homeomorphism on its image.

See for example [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2621010/an-injective-continuous-map-between-two-compact-hausdorff-spaces) for a proof.